# GitLab CI Pipeline Best Practice .NET Multiple Projects

Tags: .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci

For a project I have a .NET Core solution with multiple projects. These projects have separate Unit Tests projects. This is what the structure looks like:

```
- My Project
  - Solution
    - Project A
    - Project B
    - Test Project A
    - Test Project B
- .gitignore
- .gitlab-ci.yml
```

I've found a way to build and test Project A and Test Project A. Now I want to do the same for B. But this is just a case of 4 projects, in reality I have 40 projects. Is there a smart way of making this yml file? Making 40 different jobs seems a bit overkill and a lot of work.

For instance, in Azure you can do it something like:

```
  - stage: build all projects in solution containing .Tests extension
    tags:
      - linux_docker
    script:
      - "cd ./*/**.Tests"
      - "dotnet restore"
      - "dotnet build"
```

Comment: Have u tried adding for loop in the script portion to `cd` into each folder?

Comment: I'm now trying to use ./[solutionpath] it kinda works, but some projects use different images than others... so I'm stuck there now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test each project separately (instead of just running `dotnet test` against the solution file) you can use the GitLab CI [Parallel Matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) feature.
The CI yaml could look like this:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PROJECT
        - Test Project A
        - Test Project B
  script:
    - dotnet test 'My Project'/Solution/'${PROJECT}'
```

This way GitLab CI will create a job for each matrix variable you define and offer you the content in an environment variable. You could also set the full path instead of only the project name, but be careful to quote any directory with spaces in it in linux.